# How do NVML and NVAPI compare?

Tags: nvidia, nvapi, nvml

I want to get some basic GPU data: name, RAM size, and do temperature monitoring.

From NVIDIA docs, it's not clear which library to use. Is NVAPI a legacy API which should be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe one of the main differences is NVAPI is only available on windows

Additionally, NVML is intended for third party use:

> Each new version of NVML is backwards compatible and is intended to be a platform for building 3rd party applications.
>   https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml

NVAPI is intended for internal use:

> NVAPI is constantly and rigorously tested not only for end-users, but for internal use at NVIDIA and our closest partners.
>   https://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi

Last, NVML is mostly for monitoring. NVAPI appears to have a greater ability to set attributes on the device (such as fan speed)